# How to Paint QTreeview content

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qpainter

I'm trying to paint the content of a QTreeview in a QPixmap in order to render it in another QWidget and to print it.

Currently my code looks like that :

```
QPixmap PrintWidget::getTreeView(QTreeView* treeview){

    QAbstractItemView::ScrollMode scrollMode = treeview->verticalScrollMode();

    treeview->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex(),QItemSelectionModel::Clear);
    treeview->setVerticalScrollMode(QTreeView::ScrollPerPixel);

    int width = treeview->viewport()->size().width();
    int scrollMax = treeview->verticalScrollBar()->maximum();
    int height = treeview->maximumViewportSize().height() + scrollMax;

    int currentPosition = treeview->verticalScrollBar()->sliderPosition();

    treeview->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(0);

    QPixmap pixmap(width,height);

    QRegion region(0,0,width,height);
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);

    treeview->viewport()->render(&painter,QPoint(),region,
                                 RenderFlags(QWidget::DrawChildren|QWidget::IgnoreMask));

    treeview->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(currentPosition);
    treeview->setVerticalScrollMode(scrollMode);

    return pixmap;
}
```

This works very well if the QTreeview has already been seen by the user. The treeview appears in a tab in the main window. If the user see the treeview and then click the button that execute my above code, then all the treeview appears in the QPixmap. Otherwise only a bit of the treeview appears.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this problem is most likely related to the widget not being sized to the client's screen before attempting to render it in the QPixmap.

You could call show() on the QTreeView before painting it to the QPixmap, or you could attempt to calculate the dimensions within your method.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work :(
Even if I set width and height to arbitrary values, it always display the same small left upper part of the treeview